# Dense and continous function in topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X, Y$ be two metric  spaces and  $D$ is a dense  subset of $X$.
Let $f, g$   be Two continous function from $X$ to $Y$
  S.  t
$f(x) =g(x)$  for all $x$ in $D$. 
Then $f=g$  on  $X$.

Is this result true in arbitrary topological space??

I know  this is not true in topological space. But I can't find any example. Please give me an example.

Again this result will true in topological space provided that $Y$ is Hausdorff. But how to prove it. 
Please help me. Thank you

Comment: a) Use Mathjax to format your questions and make them readable. b) We are not here to do your homework for you. Provide context and your thoughts/what you tried lest your question be closed as off-topic.

Comment: You forgot to mention that $D$ is dense.

Comment: Sorry,  to say D is dense subset of X

Comment: I edited your post to get it to render as $\LaTeX$.  Remember, surround your math symbols ($\LaTeX$) with "\$" signs.  Thus "\$ f(x) = g(x) \$" yields $f(x) = g(x)$.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Hausdorff space $Y$  the diagonal $\Delta\subset Y\times Y$ is closed. The function

$H: X\to Y\times Y$

that maps every $x\in X$ to $H(x):=(f(x),g(x))$ is continuos and so
the inverse image of $\Delta$ twith respect the function $H$ is closed, but this set is

$D=\{x\in X : f(x)=g(x)\}$

When this set is dense you have that $D=D^{cl}=X$ and so $f=g$

If you consider a $T_1 $ connected topological space $X$ in which $S:=X/ \{p\}$ is dense in $X$ (for example $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology)  you have that

1. $X/S$ is not T_1 (and so it is not T_2) because if you consider $x\in S$ you have that $\pi^{-1}(x^\sim)=X/ \{p\}$ that it is open, so $\{x^\sim\}$ is open in $X/S$ but it  can not be closed because $\{x^\sim\}$ would be a proper closed and open set of the connected space  $X/S$ ;
2. $\pi: X\to X/S$ and $c: X\to X/S$ are continuos function, where $c$ is the constant function that maps every $z\in X$ to $\pi(S)$ ;
3. $D:=\{x\in X: \pi(x)=c(x)\}=X/ \{p\}$ and D is dense;

   $\pi\neq c$

Comment: Thank you sir.  when Y is not Hausdorff then the result is false. Can you give an example for that.?

Comment: I think there are more simply contro examples but I did not think anything else

Comment: Again thanks! But this example is very complicated.

Comment: $\frac{X}{S}$ is non-standard notation. $X / S$ is usual when identifying $S$ to a point.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counterexample: let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ in the indiscrete (trivial) topology. Let $X$ be the $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology. $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$  and $g(x) =1 $ otherwise. Then both are continuous (any map with codomain the indiscrete topology is) and they agree on the dense set $\mathbb{Q}$ but $f \neq g$.

We could also take the cofinite topology on $\mathbb{R}$ as $Y$, and use $f(x) = x, x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $g(x) = x$, for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $g(x) = x+1$, $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ to get a $T_1$ counterexample. These maps are bijections and bijections between $T_1$ spaces are always continuous. Again they agree on $\mathbb{Q}$ and are different.

The proof by Federico Falluca is fine. You could also use nets if you preferred those.

Comment: Nice example and good, simple.

Comment: @Golambiswas very often if a fact needs Hausdorffness for general spaces, a counterexample exists that is the cofinite topology or the indiscrete topology on some set.

Comment: Okkk sir. Thanku you.

Comment: in the second example by taking cofinite topology on Y, you said f and G are bijection.

Comment: But can you please explain it why these two maps are bijection.?

Comment: @Golambiswas what part of being a bijection don't you see?

Comment: Second example with cofinite topology.

Comment: @Golambiswas I understood that. But don't you see its injectivity or surjectivity?

Comment: @Golambiswas that's the first example for the trivial topology. For the cofinite one I need bijections. Another example, another pair of functions (the identity and the modified identity).

Comment: Okkk sir I understood. Thanku you so much.